# Is it possible to create a strongly-typed complex view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Object:

```
public class CountryLanguage
{
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateComplexObjectViewModel
{
    IList<CountryLanguage> SelectedCountryLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model CreateComplexObjectViewModel
@{
    IEnumerable<CountryLanguage> allCountryLanguages = GetAllFromConfigFile();
}

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCountryLanguages,
                 allCountryLanguages.Select(cl => new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = $"{cl.Country} {cl.Language}",
                                                Value = $"{cl.Country}_{cl.Language}"
                                            }))
```

When I submit this form as-is, I see the following parameters are posted:

```
SelectedCountryLanguages=US_en&SelectedCountryLanguages=US_en-US
```

Which fails to bind to the `CountryLanguage` object. If I swap everything to `string`s then it all works, but then I have to do string parsing to get the separate values

```
var selections = new List<CountryLanguage>();

foreach (string countryLanguage in model.SelectedCountryLanguages)
{
    string[] parts = countryLanguage.Split("_");
    selections.Add(new CountryLanguage
    {
        Country = parts[0],
        Language = parts[1]
    });
}
```

Is there a way I can bind the `CountryLanguage` object without having to do this additional processing?

Answer (score 0):

Specify your name argument with

```
@Html.ListBox("CountryLanguage", ...)
```

instead of ListBoxFor.

Or create a custom html tag, instead of the helper.